# Sicronizar o banco de dados do servidor com um localhost

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, replicação

preciso sincronizar dois bancos de dados para que as informações de ambos sejam iguais devido aos problemas de instabilidade da internet. pesquisando encontrei a replicação que existe no phpmyadmin, mas como utilizo um servidor em nuvem eu não poço mexer nas configurações dele para converter meu banco em mestre

Answer (score 0):

Se você não pode alterar as configurações do computador, você pode tentar fazer um Linked Server e ter uma rotina na base de dados "filha" para de tempos em tempos colher informações desse Linked Server e colocar nesta nova base de dados.
Exemplo: De 1 em 1 hora, essas informações vão ser inputadas na nova base. 
Não vai ser uma solução real time, terá um gap de informações, mas pode ser útil.

Verifica este tutorial de como criar o Linked Server, está bem detalhado:
[Criando um Linked Server do SQL Server para MySQL - Sem usar OPENQUERY;](http://dbaduarte.blogspot.com.br/2014/12/criando-um-linked-server-do-sql-server.html)